# 7 years of gap after 12th and 2 years of gap between my bachelors degree?

Tags: job-search, resume, india, employment-gaps

I completed my 12th standard in 2014, after that I wanted to be a musician however my parents didn't allow me to pursue music then I started learning myself learnt basics of guitar and music production, started working in a studio. In 2017,  worked there as part time for 6 months however since my skills weren't good enough to get me a job on salary basis.

After that I took admission in Hotel Management in 2018, I studied there for 1 year and then I quit on 3rd semester, in the mid of 2019 - I took an off to pursue music again and I started learning from a institute this time and I also started working in a studio as a mixing and mastering engineer.

In 2020 pandemic came all of a sudden and everything got shut. I started feeling insecure about my future after that I realized the importance of being a graduate because my friends in the period of lockdown, they were able to work from home and earning money. I was unable to find a job, for even basic job the requirement was bachelors degree.

So I decided to call my college to find about is there any possibility of continuing my studies again and it wasn't easy for me to call but I did and they said yes I can continue from 2nd year.

Now I have a doubt after all this year gap and making so many bad decisions in my life am I able to earn a good job in retail??

I also know that finding  a job after all this year gap is not going to be easy but I am looking for someone with similar number of year gap in their career and able to make out good by finding someone it will give me little hope and direction to my life.

Comment: We all make bad decisions. The only thing that matters is how we deal with them. Right now, I think you are seeing yourself a bit sad and negative. Try to look forward - What are your skills? Your competence is worth something. It is not a problem, if you have many skills, on the contrary, it is a gift. Try clearing your thoughts and as next step, formulate a question here in the forum, like "What next steps could help me to find a job with these and these preconditions?" or something else. Right now, I don't know what I am being asked.

Comment: Nobody can tell you whether you will find a job after finishing your bachelor's degree. And this is the wrong sort of site to ask for general career advice. We are focussed on answering specific questions with general answers. The only thing we can reasonably say is that having a degree will open up jobs that you could not have applied for without one.

Comment: I am feeling really good and confident by seeing all this people have shown concerned on my post Thank you so much !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Finish something in your life

Your problem is not switching careers. Lot of people do that, especially in modern times. And in reality, nobody cares, you came from different industry, now you are junior in this field, you could get a junior position and pay and that's it.

Your problem is **you do not finish anything**. You started career as a musician, then in 2018 changed your mind and went to Hotel Management, then went back to music but quit again, and went back to college (probably to continue with Hotel Management) . Pattern any future employer would see is a pattern of quitter. Person not sure what he wants to be, and giving up at first obstacle.

My suggestion would be to finally finish that Hotel Management course. If you have to work while studying so be it. Difficulties in life would build your character. When you get that degree, your confidence will rise. You will be able to say " I did something in my life" . Then you will continue with job search and start building your career.

Comment: Wanting to listen to music is not the same thing as being a musician professionally. You probably should consult people and figure out the difference between you try to switch to music as a career.

Comment: @Nelson OP said he was professional or semi-professional sound engineer.

Answer (score 0):

> I was unable to find a job, for even basic job the requirement was bachelors degree.

You're not looking for the right sort of job then. If you need to work you apply for jobs you're qualified or experienced at, or those that require neither.

Comment: A british banker visited India once for a banking summit and decided to check out some indian banks to find out how they work. Later, at the summit, an indian banker asked him what he thought of the indian banking system. He said, *"One thing was odd - why do you hire graduates for a clerical job that a high school student can do?"*. The indian replied, *"Why would I hire someone with a high school diploma when I can hire a graduate?"*. Read   https://thewire.in/labour/tamil-nadu-7000-professionals-apply-for-549-sanitation-worker-posts for another perspective.

Comment: Because graduates cost more money.  In the example there is an apparently oversaturated market, however the salary of the government position was apparently very high compared to market standards. Had it not been, then personnel of higher qualification had been less likely to be attracted.

Comment: @Koenigsberg Yes, you can find fresh graduates to work for peanuts in India, because there are so many graduates out there and the falling economy of India has ensured that employers can exploit them.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you did make some bad choices along the way.

But it isn't all bad as you make it out to be.

The main problem is that even with a degree in Hotel Management, you will be competing at a disadvantage after you graduate - your age and lack of experience in this field. (And working in a service industry like this can be a soul-sucking experience).

A suggestion I have is to instead do a degree in the field you have interest and experience in, i.e. the music industry. With what you have shared, I recommend getting a degree in "**Sound & Music Technology**". It is a 3 years course which can qualify you to work as an *Audio Visual Specialist* or *Media and Event Support Specialist* or *Keyboard and Studio Recording Specialist* or *Music Instructor* or *Studio Engineer* or *Studio Manager* etc. This way, you ensure that your past experience at studios, even if short, is not wasted.

However, note that a lot depends on the college you get this degree from. And a job in the music industry is tough to get. Even if you do get one, it may not be financially as worthwhile in the long term. Since you have already worked in this industry, I suggest you to talk to senior people in the studio / music industry and find out from them if you can make a worthwhile career in the industry if you get a degree in Sound & Music Technology. (Note that there are other degrees in this field like learning instruments or vocalists etc. Since people in the industry have already pointed out that you lack talent in this area, I strongly urge you not to consider these. It's too much of a risk, and if you waste any more time, it will be difficult to get back on track and find a suitable career.)

Worst case, whatever degree you get, you will have to build up experience. In such a scenario, I recommend you look for a sales job in any good company after your degree. It's tough work, but can be financially rewarding if you can perform above average. And you can always get an MBA after a few years, and craft a good corporate career in any industry.